# How to convert pyplot.contour(..) to opencv equivalent?

Tags: opencv, matplotlib, contour

I have an image like this: (original.png)

[image: original image]

and human detection result like this: (detection.png)

[image: detected heatmap]

and using blow code:

```
import numpy
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

original  = cv2.imread('original.png')
detections = cv2.imread('detection.png')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12,12])
plt.imshow( original[:,:,::-1] )
plt.contour( detections[:,:,1]/256.,10, linewidths = 1 )
plt.contour( detections[:,:,2]/256.,10, linewidths = 1 )
plt.axis('off') ;
plt.show()
```

will generate image like this:
[image: with contours]
I have tried to convert this:

```
plt.contour( detections[:,:,1]/256.,10, linewidths = 1 )
```

to opencv equivalent:

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(detections,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

with all kinds combination of

```
retrieve mode + approximation method
```

but none of them gives expected result,,so how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCv findcontours expects a black and white image.

Try:

```
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(detections[:,:,1], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```